# NIO DatagramSocket in Android. I receive nothing or 0

Tags: java, android, sockets, nio

I am using sockets to communicate with the device. I am communicating with the socket on an arbitrary port with a timeout of 1 second and in the other threads, I have  passed this instance of the socket.
I interact with them in the following ways:

- Periodic interrogation (every 4 seconds) - this is required by the
  device otherwise it will exit the "capture" mode. I use the built-in
  mechanism Android-Timer;

  I am using thread in order to get the data and send the data to the device in request/response. After
  that, the thread is stopping (not in a loop);
- A stream that must constantly rotate and receive only the necessary
  data packets, the rest ignore. I run it and it just needs to spin (In
  it, then the whole problem, before this did without it).

The problem is the following: when you enter step 3, the application stops working, as if the socket is always busy. Example code (class from the above item 3):

```
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Message
import com.controller.labaratory.controller.App
import com.controller.labaratory.controller.models.Container
import java.net.*

/**
 * Created by ivan on 03/08/17.
 */
class DataPacketThread(val handler: Handler,
                       val socket: DatagramSocket,
                       val addres: InetAddress):Thread() {


    override fun run() {
        super.run()
        while (!socket.isClosed){
            try{
                //socket.soTimeout=0
                var buffer:ByteArray = kotlin.ByteArray(1024)
                val packet = DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.size)

                socket?.receive(packet)

                val odin:Byte = -1

                if (!(buffer[0] == odin)){
                    if(packet.data[0].toInt() == 4){
                        val responseByteArray:ByteArray = byteArrayOf(1,33,
                                packet.data[2],packet.data[3])

                        val packetResponseAnswer = DatagramPacket(responseByteArray,
                                responseByteArray.size, addres, 1026)
                        socket?.send(packetResponseAnswer)

                        handler?.sendMessage(
                                Message.obtain(
                                        handler,
                                        App.UdpClientHandler.DATA_PACKET_RECEIVE,
                                        HandlerContainer(825, Container(
                                                packet.length,
                                                packet.data))))
                    }

                }
            } catch (e:SocketTimeoutException){
                e.printStackTrace()
            } catch (e:SocketException){
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

        }
    }

    fun end(){
        socket.close()
    }
}
```

In accordance with what I want to do from the previous question, I have two options:

- Organize everything on blocking sockets. I put all the work into one
  thread, but I encountered difficulties (speed of response, requests
  periodically disappear, work with video stream is possible in the
  future)
- Understand the non-blocking sockets. I tried various examples - I
  could not earn any of them. I get either nothing or 0.

In order not to be unfounded, I created a repository on the githab, where I laid out all my [attempts](https://github.com/IvanShalimov/NIOLearn)

Tell me what to do. What I misunderstand. What I'm doing wrong

The task is the following, it is necessary to make one of the ways to interact with the device over the network:

1. Keep one thread in the program and in it organize the request queue. The loop in the thread works continuously, checking whether there is anything to send and receive. After sending, there will be a block where we read the incoming.
2. You can make one thread that will constantly work with the loop and listen in it, and in separate threads send requests.

Blocking sockets failed to write a single working example in one thread, only in different threads. As a result, it turned out to be a competitor for the socket. On non-blocking, it was not possible to get even a primitive query / response.

Comment: I'm not convinced that you problem/s are not just simply because of a poor 'ping-pong' application protocol on top of the unreliable UDP IP protocol.  You will not be able to support video in such a manner:(

Comment: Now there is no video. Only data exchange.

Comment: This is not Java code. What is 'step 3'? Unclear what you're asking.